# SQL query to get maximum of all maximum values per customer

Tags: sql, group-by, ms-access-2010, max, greatest-n-per-group

I'm struggling with this specific Access 2010 SQL query for quite some time now. Let me first show you what my table looks like:

```
customerID     value
123456789        100
123456789       -100
123456789        300
123456789       -300
123456789        150
123456789       -150
123456789        200
123456789        200
987654321        500
987654321       -500
987654321        200
987654321       -200
987654321        210
987654321        210
```

You see I have multiple entries for one customerID with several values. These values can be positive and negative. Negative values represent corrections so the corresponding positive value "gets nulled".

What I need to query now is the maximum value of all maximum values per customerID. In the example above, the maximum value of customerID 123456789 is 200, because all other values on this customerID annul each other. The maximum value on customerID 987654321 hence is 210.

Ultimately my query should return the value of 210 as the maximum out of all maximum values per customerID that didn't get corrected/anulled by negative values.

Can you please help me with this?

Edit: Added (duplicate) values 200 and 210 to both customerIDs to make clear that a SUM() wont work here.

Edit #2: Here's some (nearly) real life data: http://pastebin.com/TbNRTw5A

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this would be your answer, it's just assuming that all negative values have 1 corresponding equal positive value paired up.

```
SELECT CustomerID, SUM(Stack1.Value) FROM Stack1 
GROUP BY CustomerID
```

So the result would be:

```
CustomerID  Value
123456789   200
987654321   210
```

Hope this helps

---

How about this?

```
WITH tmpPositive AS (SELECT 
    Stack1.CustomerID, Stack1.Value FROM Stack1 WHERE Stack1.Value > 0),
   tmpNegative AS (SELECT 
    Stack1.CustomerID, Stack1.Value FROM Stack1 WHERE Stack1.Value < 0)
SELECT tmpPositive.CustomerID, MAX(tmpPositive.Value) AS MaxValue FROM tmpPositive
LEFT OUTER JOIN tmpNegative 
ON tmpPositive.CustomerID = tmpNegative.CustomerID AND
   -tmpPositive.Value = tmpNegative.Value
WHERE tmpNegative.CustomerID IS NULL
GROUP BY tmpPositive.CustomerID;
```

Here's the test data:

```
CustomerID Value
---------------------
123456789 100
123456789 -100
123456789 300
123456789 -300
123456789 150
123456789 -150
123456789 200
987654321 500
987654321 -500
987654321 200
987654321 -200
987654321 210
123456789 200
123456789 110
987654321 1250
```

And the result I have for above query.

```
CustomerID  MaxValue
--------------------
123456789   200
987654321   1250
```

Comment: That's the problem. There may be customerIDs with only positive values and no corresponding negative value which I guess makes joining difficult. These positive values may also be exactly the same so there are multiple completely redundant entries.

And just for the record I dind't build that database. ;-)

Comment: @Popopinsel You don't need to do a join. The positive/negative pairs cancel each other out when the SUM() is performed because they belong to the same CustomerID, which is how that query does its GROUP BY. Then, if you want to find the maximum of the values returned by that (per-CustomerID) query, just wrap it in another `SELECT MAX(Value) ...` query.

Comment: But, again, if there are no pairs of positive and negative values but only positives (whether identical or different) then a SUM() would not return the maximum value. Obviously it would return the sum of all positive values instead.

Comment: Updated answer looks interesting (I'd upvote the answer again if that were possible). Too bad that Access SQL doesn't support CTEs, though....

Comment: @Popopinsel Does the input data need to be processed sequentially? Please see the Pastebin [here](http://pastebin.com/RqX4yGLC) for a more complete explanation of what I mean.

Comment: @GordThompson Your second assumption is correct, in your Pastebin case it should return 300 and 500. Although in my real life case there can only be +/- pairs and/or identical values. As I said +/- pairs are corrected values (so there always follows a positive value) and those identical values get written to the table because they are still valid (there are several other columns/fields in this table where values get changed that's why in my case there can be identical values).

Comment: @Popopinsel Excellent, real data always helps. Would this table happen to have an incrementing AutoNumber field to help us reliably determine the order in which the rows were inserted?

Comment: @GordThompson Unfortunately no.

Comment: @Popopinsel Okay then, without an AutoNumber field or a timestamp field or some other way to do an unequal join I'm fairly certain that there's no (practical) way to do what you want using just Access SQL. However, some VBA code could probably do it....

Comment: Hi @Popopinsel, sorry that I did not carefully read your post that you were looking running it in Access SQL.  Maybe you can do it in code like the query does, spitting data into two lists of positive and negative values, and subtract them by trying to pair them up. and MAX() the remaining values?

Comment: (cc: @Popopinsel ) Hi, Alex. That would be the basic approach, but I believe that it would have to be done sequentially, row by row. See the Pastebin [here](http://pastebin.com/sBF4Ah47) for the reason why a set-based approach will be problematic. Perhaps Popopinsel will indicate whether a row-by-row VBA solution would be acceptable.

Comment: Hi Gord, Thanks for the info. The WHERE "tmpNegative.CustomerID IS NULL" assumes that the data is not equally paired. which causes the problem.